# How to use the VHDL Generic Counter I was given in my code along with creating a working testbench

Tags: generics, vhdl, counter

I am learning VHDL and trying to use this generic counter I was given to work with my clock signal. The assignment includes simulating traffic lights in a safe manner while also providing a night mode (flashing red on way and yellow the other) along with a left turn mode/signal. Unfortunately, I am unsure on how to actually use the gen_counter and what to call out in my code so it operates correctly. This is the generic counter I am trying to use:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity gen_counter is
-- we are using the generic construct to allow this counter to be generic.
generic (
        wide : positive; -- how many bits is the counter
        max  : positive  -- what is the max value of the counter ( modulus )
        );
port (
        clk  :in  std_logic; -- system clock
        data     :in  std_logic_vector( wide-1 downto 0 ); -- data in for parallel load, use unsigned(data) to cast to unsigned
        load     :in  std_logic; -- signal to load data into i_count i_count <= unsigned(data);
        enable :in  std_logic; -- clock enable
        reset_n  :in  std_logic; -- reset to zeros use i_count <= (others => '0' ) since size depends on generic
        count    :out std_logic_vector( wide-1 downto 0 ); -- count out
        term     :out std_logic -- maximum count is reached
        );
end;

architecture rtl of gen_counter is
signal i_count : unsigned (wide-1 downto 0); 

begin

count <= std_logic_vector(i_count); 

counter: process(clk, reset) begin
  if (reset_n='1') then -- active high reset
     i_count <= (others => '0'); -- set counter to 0's
     term    <= '0';  -- want the terminal count off on reset
  elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
    term <='0';
    if (load = '1') then  -- load takes priority
           i_count <= unsigned(data);
    elsif (enable = '1') then -- if enabled the counter is running.
       if (i_count=max) then -- the max value is hit, synchronously set to '0's
          term <='1'; -- we only want this active for 1 clock cycle
         i_count<=(others=>'0');
       else -- increment the counter
          term <= '0'; -- disable to term count, so only high for 1 clock cycle
         i_count <= i_count + 1;
      end if; 
    end if;
   end if;
end process;

end;
```

Below is how I am trying to use the generic counter right now. In my entity `base`, I use generic and call out the initial wide and max (50MHz clock). I need 1, 2, 4 and 6 second counters. Since the clock is 50MHz, I used the initial set values for `wide` and `max` for the 1 sec counter. For the rest, I used a 4 bit counter. In my state machine, I used the 'term' signal as my counter which is what I think may be causing my problems

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity base is 
generic (
  sim_wide : positive := 28;         --width
  sim_max  : positive := 50000000   --max value
  ); 
port (
    --clocks
    MAX10_CLK1_50           :   in      std_logic;

    --seven seg
    HEX0, HEX1, HEX2,
    HEX3, HEX4, HEX5        :   out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    --general human interface
    KEY                     :   in      std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    SW                          :   in      std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    LEDR                        :   out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
    );

end entity;-- End entity    

architecture lite of base is
--state types
    type north is (north_green,north_yellow,north_red,north_ltgn,north_ltyw,north_night0,north_night1,north_start,nwait);
    type east is (east_green,east_yellow,east_red,east_ltgn,east_ltyw,east_night0,east_night1,ewait);

    signal ncurrent_state: north;
    signal nnext_state: north;
    signal ecurrent_state: east;
    signal enext_state: east;

-- signals to be used
    signal enable_pulse_every_one_second: std_logic;    --enables a pulse every 1 second
    signal enable_pulse_every_two_second: std_logic;    --enables a pulse every 2 seconds
    signal enable_pulse_every_four_second: std_logic;   --enables a pulse every 4 seconds
    signal enable_pulse_every_six_second: std_logic;    --enables a pulse every 6 seconds
    signal reset_n: std_logic;          --reset signal
    signal temp_reset_n: std_logic;

    signal night: std_logic;        --night mode signal
    signal temp_night: std_logic;
    signal ltmode: std_logic;       --left turn mode signal
    signal temp_ltmode: std_logic;
    signal nstart: std_logic;       --north/south start signal
    signal estart: std_logic;       --east/west start signal

--clock values
    signal one_second_count_value: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);    --count for 1 second
    signal two_second_count_value: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);    --count for 2 seconds
    signal four_second_count_value: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   --count for 4 seconds
    signal six_second_count_value: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);    --counter for 6 seconds

--output signals for seven seg cntrl
    signal nout0        :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal eout5        :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

--components
component gen_counter is
generic (
    wide: positive; 
    max: positive  
    );
port (                                                      --port declaration
    clk: in std_logic;
    data: in std_logic_vector(wide-1 downto 0 );
    load: in std_logic;
    enable: in std_logic;
    reset_n: in std_logic;
    count: out std_logic_vector(wide-1 downto 0 );
    term: out std_logic);
end component;  

component seven_segment_cntrl is
    port (                                                  --port declaration
        input: in unsigned(3 downto 0);             --data input
        hex: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)       --seven segment output
        );  
end component;

begin

--Reset Mode
    process (MAX10_CLK1_50,KEY(0),temp_reset_n)
        begin
            if (KEY(1) = '1') then
                temp_reset_n <= KEY(1);             --assign key0 to left turn mode
                reset_n <= temp_reset_n;
            elsif rising_edge(MAX10_CLK1_50) then
                temp_reset_n <= '0';
                reset_n  <= temp_reset_n;
            end if;
    end process;

--Night mode 
    process (MAX10_CLK1_50)
        begin
            if rising_edge(MAX10_CLK1_50) then
                temp_night <= SW(1);                    --assign sw1 to left turn mode
                night <= temp_night;
            end if;
    end process; 

-- Left turn mode
    process (MAX10_CLK1_50)
        begin
            if rising_edge(MAX10_CLK1_50) then
                temp_ltmode <= SW(0);               --assign sw0 to left turn mode
                ltmode <= temp_ltmode;
            end if; 
    end process;

----------COUNTERS----------
--counter for 1 second
one_second : gen_counter
generic map (
        wide => sim_wide, --28 bits get 50Mhz down to 1 second
        max => sim_max   --count to 50Million
        )
port map (
        clk => MAX10_CLK1_50,
        data => (others => '0'),
        load => '0',
        enable => '1',  
        reset_n => reset_n, 
        count => open,  
        term => enable_pulse_every_one_second
        );

--counter for 2 seconds         
two_second : gen_counter 
generic map (
        wide => 4,  --4 bit counter
        max => 1    --1*2=2
    )
port map (
        clk => MAX10_CLK1_50,
        data => (others => '0'),
        load => '0',
        enable => enable_pulse_every_one_second,
        reset_n => reset_n,
        count => two_second_count_value,
        term => enable_pulse_every_two_second
        );

--counter for 4 seconds
four_second : gen_counter 
generic map (
        wide => 4,  --4 bit counter
        max => 3    --1*4=4 
        )
port map (
        clk => MAX10_CLK1_50,
        data => (others => '0'),
        load => '0',   
        enable => enable_pulse_every_one_second,
        reset_n => reset_n,
        count => four_second_count_value,
        term => enable_pulse_every_four_second
        );

--counter for 6 seconds
six_second : gen_counter 
generic map (
        wide => 4,  --4 bit counter
        max => 5    --1*6=6
        )
port map (
        clk => MAX10_CLK1_50,
        data => (others => '0'),
        load => '0',   
        enable => enable_pulse_every_one_second,
        reset_n => reset_n,
        count => six_second_count_value,
        term => enable_pulse_every_six_second
        );

--North/South Reset 
    process (MAX10_CLK1_50, reset_n)
    begin
        if reset_n = '1' then
            ncurrent_state <= north_start;
        elsif rising_edge (MAX10_CLK1_50) then
            ncurrent_state <= nnext_state;
        end if;
    end process;

--East/West Reset
    process (MAX10_CLK1_50, reset_n)
    begin
        if reset_n = '1' then
            ecurrent_state <= east_red;
        elsif rising_edge (MAX10_CLK1_50) then
            ecurrent_state <= enext_state;
        end if;
    end process;

--combinational process and case statement for north/south
process(ncurrent_state,nnext_state,nstart,enable_pulse_every_one_second,enable_pulse_every_two_second,enable_pulse_every_four_second,enable_pulse_every_six_second)
    begin
            case ncurrent_state is
                when north_start =>
                    if nstart = '1' then
                        nnext_state <= north_green;
                    end if;

                when north_green =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_four_second = '1' then
                        nnext_state <= north_yellow;
                    else
                        nnext_state <= north_green;
                    end if;

                when north_yellow =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_two_second = '1' then
                        nnext_state <= nwait;
                    else
                        nnext_state <= north_yellow;
                    end if; 

                when north_red =>
                    if nstart = '1' then
                        if ltmode = '1' and night = '0' then    
                            nnext_state <= north_ltgn;
                        elsif night = '1' then
                            nnext_state <= north_night0;
                        elsif night = '0' and ltmode = '0' then
                            if enable_pulse_every_six_second = '1' then
                                nnext_state <= north_green;
                            else
                                nnext_state <= north_red;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                    else 
                        nnext_state <= north_red;
                    end if; 

                when north_ltgn =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_four_second = '1' then
                        nnext_state <= north_ltyw;
                    else
                        nnext_state <= north_ltgn;
                    end if;

                when north_ltyw =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_two_second = '1' then
                        nnext_state <= north_green;
                    else
                        nnext_state <= north_ltyw;
                    end if;

                when north_night0 =>
                    if night = '1' then
                        if enable_pulse_every_one_second = '1' then
                            nnext_state <= north_night1;
                        else 
                            nnext_state <= north_night0;
                        end if;
                    else
                        nnext_state <= north_red;
                    end if;

                when north_night1 =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_one_second = '1' then
                        nnext_state <= north_night0;
                    else 
                        nnext_state <= north_night1;
                    end if;

                when nwait =>
                    if nstart = '0' then
                        nnext_state <= north_red;
                    elsif night = '1' then
                        nnext_state <= north_night1;
                    else
                        nnext_state <= nwait;
                    end if;
            end case;
    end process;

--combinatorial process and case statement for east/west lights
process(ecurrent_state,enext_state,estart,enable_pulse_every_one_second,enable_pulse_every_two_second,enable_pulse_every_four_second,enable_pulse_every_six_second)
    begin
            case ecurrent_state is
                when ewait =>
                    if estart = '0' then
                        enext_state <= east_red;
                    elsif night = '1' then
                        enext_state <= east_night1;
                    else
                        enext_state <= ewait;
                    end if; 

                when east_green =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_four_second = '1' then
                        enext_state <= east_yellow;
                    else
                        enext_state <= east_green;
                    end if;

                when east_yellow =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_two_second = '1' then
                        enext_state <= ewait;
                    else
                        enext_state <= east_yellow;
                    end if;

                when east_red =>
                    if estart = '1' then
                        if ltmode = '1' and night = '0' then    
                            enext_state <= east_ltgn;
                        elsif night = '1' then
                            enext_state <= east_night1;
                        elsif night = '0' and ltmode = '0' then
                            if enable_pulse_every_six_second = '1' then
                                enext_state <= east_green;
                            else
                                enext_state <= east_red;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                    else 
                        enext_state <= east_red;
                    end if;     

                when east_ltgn =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_four_second = '1' then
                        enext_state <= east_ltyw;
                    else
                        enext_state <= east_ltgn;
                    end if;

                when east_ltyw =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_two_second = '1' then
                        enext_state <= east_green;
                    else
                        enext_state <= east_ltyw;
                    end if;     

                when east_night0 =>
                    if night = '1' then
                        if enable_pulse_every_one_second = '1' then
                            enext_state <= east_night1;
                        else 
                            enext_state <= east_night0;
                        end if;
                    else
                        enext_state <= ewait;
                    end if;

                when east_night1 =>
                    if enable_pulse_every_one_second = '1' then
                        enext_state <= east_night0;
                    else 
                        enext_state <= east_night1;
                    end if;
            end case;
    end process;

    out1: process (ncurrent_state)
    begin
    estart <= '0';
        case ncurrent_state is
            when north_start =>
                estart <= '0';
                nout0 <= "0000";            --green light

            when north_green =>
                estart <= '0';
                nout0 <= "0000";            --green light

            when north_yellow => 
                estart <= '0';
                nout0 <= "0001";            --yellow light

            when north_red =>
                estart <= '1';
                nout0 <= "0010";            --red light

            when north_ltgn =>
                estart <= '0';
                nout0 <= "0011";            --left turn green and red light

            when north_ltyw =>
                estart <= '0';
                nout0 <= "0100";            --left turn yellow and red light

            when north_night0 =>
                estart <= '0';
                nout0 <= "0101";            --blank

            when north_night1 =>
                estart <= '1';
                nout0 <= "0001";            --yellow light

            when nwait =>
                estart <= '1';
                nout0 <= "0010";            --red light     
        end case;
    end process out1;

    out2: process (ecurrent_state)
    begin
    nstart <= '1';
        case ecurrent_state is          

            when east_green => 
                nstart <= '0';
                eout5 <= "0000";        --green light

            when east_yellow =>
                nstart <= '0';
                eout5 <= "0001";        --yellow light

            when east_red =>
                nstart <= '1';
                eout5 <= "0010";        --red light

            when east_ltgn =>
                nstart <= '0';
                eout5 <= "0011";        --left turn green and red light

            when east_ltyw =>
                nstart <= '0';
                eout5 <= "0100";        --left turn yellow and red light

            when east_night0 =>
                nstart <= '0';
                eout5 <= "0101";        --blank

            when east_night1 =>
                nstart <= '0';
                eout5 <= "0010";        --red light

            when ewait =>
                nstart <= '1';
                eout5 <= "0010";        --red light 
        end case;
    end process out2;

hex1 <= (others => '1');
hex2 <= (others => '1');
hex3 <= (others => '1');
hex4 <= (others => '1');

        hex5_driver: seven_segment_cntrl
          port map(
             input => unsigned(eout5),
             hex   => HEX5
             );  
        hex0_driver: seven_segment_cntrl
          port map(
             input => unsigned(nout0),
             hex   => HEX0
             ); 
end architecture;
```

Here is seven_seg_cntrl that is being used:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY seven_segment_cntrl IS
    PORT (
        input : IN UNSIGNED(3 DOWNTO 0);
        hex : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 downto 0)
    );  
END ENTITY seven_segment_cntrl;

ARCHITECTURE logic OF seven_segment_cntrl IS
signal seven_seg : std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);  -- upper bit is seg_a, lower bit is seg_g
BEGIN
    hex(6 downto 0) <= not seven_seg(0) & not seven_seg(1) & not seven_seg(2)&
                        not seven_seg(3) & not seven_seg(4) & not seven_seg(5)& 
                              not seven_seg(6);

    PROCESS (input)
    BEGIN
        CASE input IS
            WHEN  "0000" =>  -- 7-segment display green light when input equals "0000"
              seven_seg <= "0001000"; 
            WHEN  "0001" =>  -- 7-segment display yellow light when input equals "0001"
              seven_seg <= "0000001"; 
            WHEN  "0010" =>  -- 7-segment display red light when input equals "0010"
              seven_seg <= "1000000"; 
            WHEN  "0011" =>  -- 7-segment display red w/ LT green when input equals "0011"
              seven_seg <= "1000010";  
            WHEN  "0100" =>  -- 7-segment display red w/ LT yellow when input equals "0100"
              seven_seg <= "1000100"; 
            WHEN  "0101" =>  -- 7-segment display "_" when input equals "0100"
              seven_seg <= "0000000";
            WHEN OTHERS =>   -- 7-segment display 'E' for error
              seven_seg <= "1001111";  
        END CASE;
    END PROCESS;
END ARCHITECTURE logic;
```

My board is just showing the 'north_green' on the 7 segment and not going anywhere from there which makes me think it's a clock issue. Modelsim is not showing me anything either. I'm not sure if the `term` signal is the correct one to use for a counter, so I need assistance in how to use this generic clock within my code to get the correct pulses I need. Also, I want to note that my code does compile without errors as is. Thank you in advance

EDIT: Here is my testbench (that is clearly not working). The area between `-- add more vectors to test everything` and `end process;` is apparently the only part we are allowed to edit.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity lite_tb is
end entity;

architecture behav of lite_tb is

component base is
port (
    --clocks

    MAX10_CLK1_50           :   in      std_logic;

    --seven seg
    HEX0, HEX1, HEX2,
    HEX3, HEX4, HEX5        :   out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    --general human interface
    KEY                     :   in      std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    SW                          :   in      std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    LEDR                        :   out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)

);
end component;

constant CLK_PER:time := 20 ns;
constant clk_cycle:time := 2*clk_per;

signal aclr_n : std_logic;
signal clk    : std_logic;
signal sw     : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
signal key    : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal ledr   : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
signal hex0   : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); -- right most
signal hex1   : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);   
signal hex2   : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);   
signal hex3   : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);   
signal hex4   : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);   
signal hex5   : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0); -- left most

begin


    clock:process begin  -- this process just continues to run as the simulation time continues
         clk <= '0';
         wait for CLK_PER;
         clk <= '1';
         wait for CLK_PER;
         end process;



    vectors:process begin -- put you test vectors here, remember to advance the simulation in modelsim

        aclr_n <= '0';      -- assert the asynchronous reset signal
        sw     <= "0000000000"; -- drive all the switch inputs to a 0
        wait for 5 ns;          -- wait for a fraction of the clock so stimulus is not occuring on clock edges
        aclr_n <= '1';          -- release the reset signal

        wait for 2*clk_cycle; --  wait for a number of clock cycles


        -- add more vectors to test everything
        sw     <= "0000000001"; 
        wait for 2*clk_cycle; 
        wait for 2000 ns; 
        sw     <= "0000000000";

        wait for 2*clk_cycle;   

        sw     <= "0000000010"; 
        wait for 2*clk_cycle;
        wait for 2000 ns;           

        aclr_n <= '0';      
        sw     <= "0000000000"; 
        wait for 5 ns;          
        aclr_n <= '1';          

        end process;

key(1) <= aclr_n;
key(0) <= clk;


-- instantiate the device under test (dut)
dut :base
port map (
    --clocks

    MAX10_CLK1_50   => clk,         

    --seven seg
    HEX0        => hex0,
    HEX1        => hex1,
    HEX2        => hex2,
    HEX3        => hex3,
    HEX4        => hex4,
    HEX5        => hex5,
    --general human interface
    KEY         => key,             
    SW          => sw,                      
    LEDR        => ledr     

);
end architecture;
```

With Modelsim, I cannot get a display of my signals other than [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AceGQ.jpg) no matter what I change in my code or TB.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my code and the tips you were able to include with the snippets of code I originally posted. I edited my post to include everything in my code instead of snippets. Unfortunately, I have to use the gen_counter included. Hopefully the whole code can make this easier to determine the issue at hand.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I added seven_segment and the clauses needed. Also, I'm struggling to write a working testbench for some reason. I can get a baseline but whenever I try to add in keys or switches, they don't display any signals in Modelsim. I will look over what you have mentioned and see if I can get any further with this information. Thanks again

Comment: Firstly, I want to truly apologize for my incompetence on the topic as I am essentially trying to teach myself through this course. The assignment includes simulating traffic lights in a safe manner while also providing a night mode (flashing red on way and yellow the other) along with a left turn mode/signal. I added my testbench above.

Comment: I don't believe we are able to edit outside of the specified boundary, but I am willing to do so if it makes things less confusing. I found it odd also that clk was assigned to a key, and am not sure why that is. I also reassigned reset_n to key(1) to match aclr_n in the testbench. What are the two flip flops that you're referring to? These flip flops need to be deleted along with the 5 ns pulse increased to greater than 20 ns?

Comment: There a a few things about the reset. First gen_counter and base use reset_n = '1' for a reset condition, yet the part of the testbench process you can't overwrite shows a negative true reset (in keeping with the name reset_nOT). Second reset_n should use KEY(1). Third You can't use an asynchronous reset to control a synchronous process.You only need the first one provided above the comment `-- add more vectors to test everything`. And then you get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjQnt.jpg).

Comment: I used a clks_per_sec generic to reduce the simulation effort. I also only put 5 statements below  `-- add more vectors to test everything` ( `wait for 15 sec;`, `sw(0) <= '1';` `wait for 50 sec;`, `sw(1) <= '1';` and `wait;`) then simulated for 100 seconds. You should be able to replicate the functionality on the FPGA board. You still haven't provided a clear description of what trouble you're having with the testbench. (And I temporarily removed the clock from key(0) in the testbench to reduce visual noise.)

Comment: Thank you again for spending so much time on this. I did everything you mentioned and either I am still missing something or something else is terribly wrong. My Modelsim simulation has looked like [this](https://imgur.com/gYSKPt7) no matter what I do, even after putting in `-- add more vectors to test everything ( wait for 15 sec;, sw(0) <= '1'; wait for 50 sec;, sw(1) <= '1'; and wait;`. I will add my Modelsim problem to the original post.

Comment: Your linked image image does not show the mandated aclr_n '0' pulse at the beginning of simulation nor clk and doesn't contain enough information for discovering your problem. [A reset problem does show up in your last question edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuXuQ.jpg) (if KEY(1) = '0' then temp_reset_n <= '1'; reset_n <= '1'; on the right in my version, note the sensitivity list change, too.). All your hex outputs [should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThSir.jpg). I had to sketch out a schematic for the two flip flops (temp_reset_n and reset_n) to get it right. Let us know if this helps.